# How to simulate a time-dependent AR(2) model?

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, autoregressive

I'm working with time series and I need to simulate a time-dependent AR(2) model like this:

$Y_t = a_tY_{t−1} − 0.5Y_{t−2} + \epsilon_t ,t =1, 2, ..., 1024,$

where $a_t=0.8*cos(t)$

How can I implement that ?

Comment: Probably, I am missing something.  But, I think I would set $Y_{-1}=Y_{-2}=0$, draw $\epsilon_0$, calculate $Y_0$.  Then, draw $\epsilon_1$, calculate $Y_1$.  Then keep going for a million draws.  Then you can start generating the data you actually use.  That will work if the series is ergodic and a million is "big enough" to make initial conditions not matter.  Without actually learning a bunch of time series I've forgotten, I couldn't prove the above series is ergodic (though I don't see why it wouldn't be).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I also thought about that solution. I'm looking for something more efficient.